# Parse File upload suddenly doesn't upload anymore

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Yesterday i tested my app and the upload function was working with no issues and today as i made some changes it stopped working, then i undone the changes and the application is still not uploading

```
bUpload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.bUpload:
                    Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) UploadFile.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    new UploadFile(image, FileSelector.getText().toString());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] FiletoUpload = stream.toByteArray();

                    ParseFile File = new ParseFile("file1.jpeg", FiletoUpload);
                    File.saveInBackground();

                    ParseObject UploadedFiles = new ParseObject("UploadedFiles");
                    UploadedFiles.put("ImageName", "Uploaded Files");
                    UploadedFiles.put("ImageFile", File);
                    UploadedFiles.saveInBackground();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File Uploaded Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: set a callback in `saveInBackground`. What is the error you get?

Comment: all i did was change the ParseObject name and it started uploading again, i have no idea why is that!

Comment: You should follow @adnsbr advice and set a callback for your `saveInBackground` method call. You would know if there's an error

Comment: @BartoszLipinski thank you for the advice, I will it seems to be a good way to handle errors